# How can I dynamically duplicate a view, change the id of the duplicated view, and add it to the same parent in Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Say I have this layout below in xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_length_0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:dividerPadding="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_a_0"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="handleClickButton"
                    android:text="A" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_b_0"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="handleClickButton"
                    android:text="B" />

            </LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_done"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:text="Done"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container_scroll" />
```

When the button with the id btn_done is pressed, I want to duplicate the linear layout container_length_0, change the new duplicate view to container_length_1, and add the new duplicated view to another linear layout. The original container_length_0 must not be affected. I would really appreciate any and all assistance you guys can provide.

Comment: You can not do such thing you can surly generate IDs dynamically but it won't be `container_length_1` and `container_length_2` . Why don't you just use a `RecyclerView`?  Or if you are bound to use `addView` in layout just add the same view and access it by `getChildAt(int index)` .

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new `Layout` resource file, put your sample `Layout` code in it.
2. Use `inflater.inflate()` to inflate this sample `Layout`, set its `id`,  and add it to the target parent `View`:

   ```
   val sampleView = layoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample, null).apply {
       id = 123
   }

   parentView.addView(sampleView)
   ```